# How to add property to JSON object in SQL Server column

Tags: sql-server

One of my table has JSON data in a SQL Server database. I need to add new property to  existing JSON.

Example of JSON data in Table:

```
{ "FirstName": "John" }
```

What I need is to add another property to this column.

```
{ "FirstName": "Jonh","City":"Pune" }
```

I tried to use JSON_MODIFY function but it is throwing error. Does this work only with array?

Code which I tried:

```
update <TableName> 
set <jsonColumnName> = JSON_MODIFY(<jsonColumnName>, '$.', JSON_QUERY(N'{ "City":"Pune" }'))
where UserId = 1
```

Error message:

> JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you want this syntax:

```
UPDATE <TableName>
SET <jsonColumnName>=JSON_MODIFY(<jsonColumnName>,'$.City','Pune')
WHERE UserId=1
```

Answer (score 9):

***Example to Add, Update and Delete a Property From JSON***

**Sample Table and Data**

```
declare @Table table
    (JsonColumn varchar(max))

insert into @Table
values
('{"FirstName": "John"}')

select * from  @Table
```

**Insert New Property**

```
UPDATE @Table
SET JsonColumn=JSON_MODIFY(JsonColumn,'$.City','Pune')

select * from  @Table
```

**Update Existing Property**

```
UPDATE @Table
SET JsonColumn=JSON_MODIFY(JsonColumn,'$.City','Delhi')

select * from  @Table
```

**Update Multiple Existing Properties**

```
UPDATE @Table
SET JsonColumn= JSON_MODIFY(JSON_MODIFY(JsonColumn,'$.City','Delhi'), '$.FirstName', 'Mukesh')

select * from  @Table
```

**Delete Existing Property**

```
UPDATE @Table
SET JsonColumn=JSON_MODIFY(JsonColumn,'$.City',null)

select * from  @Table
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you need to use append with JSON_Modify. Something like this:

```
UPDATE <TableName>
SET <jsonColumnName> = JSON_MODIFY(<jsonColumnName>, 'append $', JSON_QUERY(N'{"City":"Pune"}'))
WHERE UserId=1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already tried this but didn't work. I guess append works only with array.  "Java Devil" 's answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that [Gauravsa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55231390/10451394) is helpful when storing an object to the JSON property otherwise it would be stored as a deserialized object.

An example usage is:

```
UPDATE [TableName]
SET [jsonColumnName]=JSON_MODIFY([jsonColumnName],'$.secondaryActionColor', JSON_QUERY(N'{"alpha":1,"hex":"#FFC600","hexa":"#FFC600FF","hsla":{"h":46.588235294117645,"s":1,"l":0.5,"a":1},"hsva":{"h":46.588235294117645,"s":1,"v":1,"a":1},"hue":46.588235294117645,"rgba":{"r":255,"g":198,"b":0,"a":1}}'))
WHERE UserId=1;
```